# Python - How can i open multiple browser windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, window

I am new to python and I will be using the code below to open a browser window and do some things. However, when I open multiple URLs simultaneously, it just opens a new tab in the existing browser window, but I want it to open in a new window and then open more tabs on the new window(s). Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import webbrowser

#path for the driver
driver  = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\mydriver\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("window.open ('https://www.google.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

driver.execute_script("window.open ('https://www.bing.com','https://www.facebook.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: There's this article that might be of help. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import webbrowser

#path for the driver
driver  = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\mydriver\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("window.open ('https://www.google.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

for page in ('https://www.bing.com','https://www.facebook.com'):
    driver.execute_script(f"window.open ('{page}')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but that still opened all the URLs in the same window, I need to open multiple windows and further open multiple URLs on them

Answer (score 0):

Insert this where you want open and switch to a new tab.
`driver.execute_script("window.open('https://website.com')")`
`driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[TAB])`

Replace the TAB variable with the tab you want to switch to (ex. if you opened one new tab put "2" in the TAB variable's place.)